# Bash: How to chown of two file extensions in one line?

Tags: bash, shell

How may i merge these two lines into one line?

```
chown abc:abc *.sh

chown abc:abc *.txt
```

Change ownership of two file extensions into one liner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
chown abc:abc *.txt *.sh
```

Or if you really want to get fancy:

```
chown abc:abc *.{txt,sh}
```

Comment: +1, although "fancy" would be something like `find . \( -name '*.txt' -or -name '*.sh' \) -maxdepth 0 -print0 | xargs -0 chown abc:abc {} ';'` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: no, you're confusing fancy with demented (ok, yes I'm guilty of using abominations like that, but I'm demented so it's ok).

Comment: Note that the brace syntax is not portable to basic Bourne shell.

Comment: I realize it might be on purpose, but the find + xargs version is over-complicated. In particular, `xargs -r0 chown abc:abc` at the end is quite sufficient.

Comment: @triplee: what does -r do on xargs? Darwin's xargs doesn't have that option...

Comment: Oh, I just typed that out of habit.  It will not run the command if there was no input into `xargs`.